# C# mongod- insert fails with "unable to connect to server, attempted to read past the stream"

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am able to create a successful connection to a remote mongodb server and database. When I try and insert the document into a collection I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server xxx.xxx.x.xx:28017: Attempted to read past the end of the stream..
```

after a little lag. I am not sure what the issue is if the connection seems fine.

```
        server = New MongoClient("mongodb://admin:password@xxx.xxx.x.xx:28017/").GetServer
        db = server.GetDatabase("TestDB")
        mongoC = db("TestCpo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that Mongo is up and running? Open up a command line, navigate to the location of your mongo installation then to the bin directory, type in "mongod". This will start up the mongo server, you need to have the mongo server up and running before you can do anything with it.

It's also useful to add the path to your environment variables so that it can be set up easier.

Another thing you could do is use

```
Process.Start(@"C:\[Directory of the mongo installation]\bin\mongod.exe");
```

(this is probably more useful if you want to start Mongo under test conditions)